# Erlang Parse_trans Form translate to Erlang Source Code

Tags: erlang

By using parse_trans I am getting the Form of the module.. Then I am doing some modifications to it.. Is there a way to translate the Form back to actual erlang code? Say the form is as follows:

```
[{attribute,1,file,
        {"/program.erl",
         1}},
{attribute,1,module,program},
{attribute,3,export,[{run,0}]},
{function,5,run,0,
       [{clause,5,[],[],
                [{match,5,
                        {var,5,'T'},
                        {cons,5,
                              {atom,40,program},
                              {cons,5,{atom,40,...},{cons,...}}}},
                 {call,5,
                       {remote,5,{atom,5,advices},{atom,5,before_advice}},
                       [{var,5,'T'}]},
                 {match,5,{var,5,'R'},{call,5,{atom,5,run_@},[]}},
                 {var,5,'R'}]}]},
{function,5,run_@,0,
       [{clause,5,[],[],
                [{call,6,
                       {remote,6,{atom,6,program2},{atom,6,calc_service}},
                       [{integer,6,1},{integer,6,0}]},
                 {call,7,
                       {remote,7,{atom,7,program2},{atom,7,calc_service}},
                       [{integer,7,2},{integer,7,2}]},
                 {call,8,
                       {remote,8,{atom,8,program2},{atom,8,process_message}},
                       [{string,8,"Add 3 to 5"}]},
                 {call,9,
                       {remote,9,{atom,9,program2},{atom,9,...}},
                       [{string,9,"Message to process"}]},
                 {call,10,{remote,10,{atom,10,...},{atom,...}},[]},
                 {atom,11,ok}]}]},
{eof,11}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [erl_pp:form/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_pp.html#form-1).
Here is an example:

```
parse_transform(Forms, _Options) ->
    IOList = [erl_pp:form(Form) || Form <- Forms],
    io:format(user, "~s", [IOList]),
    Forms.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty-printer from parse_trans application: https://github.com/esl/parse_trans/blob/master/src/parse_trans_pp.erl